# Create backup of MySQL database alongside Features module

Tags: database, features, backups

When collaborating with other developers, we are using Features module and push it to a repository, this way the files can be pulled to the developer's own development environment.

Our problem is the database.  What we do is export a SQL dump, and send it. Then import the SQL dump.

Is there a better way on handling database backups? Since I believe that Features module can't export the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to encapsulate *every* db configuration value into a Feature. And, Features was never designed to do that. A Feature was originally supposed to be a re-usable site component.

To capture more fully site configuration look at the [Configuration](https://drupal.org/project/configuration) module:

> The configuration management module enables the ability to keep track
>   of specific configurations on a Drupal site, provides the ability to
>   move these configurations between different environments (local, dev,
>   qa, prod), and also move configurations between completely different
>   sites (migrate configurations) without the use of modules with all
>   configuration being owned by the site.
>
> For the most part this module provides the same functionality as a
>   subset of the features module. Features module is currently the go to
>   tool for moving configuration from environment to environment and site
>   to site, and it does a great job doing this, but "configuration
>   management" was never really what features was intended to do. The
>   goal of features module was to group configurations together to
>   satisfy a certain use-case. Instead most people use features to export
>   configuration to code to ease with deployment between environments.
>   Many of us have experienced the shortcomings of using features module
>   for configuration management and found where it doesn't quite work to
>   easily manage configuration. A couple other modules have spawned off
>   to help with some of these shortcomings: features override, features
>   plumber, Features Tools.

Additionally since not everything can be captured in Features, look into building your site via a `Installation Profile` where you can codify new Users, Content Types and custom variables as well.

I am currently using Features + an Installation Profile to *build* a webapp that lets notified individuals via email submit a Drupal Webform via a secretly keyed url parameter. You can use features (to an extent) but you really have to use many small features to get the job done, and not all modules play well with Features (like exporting Webforms, which requires node_export, uuid and THEN features) ...